# Set Height of a listbx fit to content

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have to set a list box which shows data from database column . Each time different length of data will come to list-box. so according to this I have to change its height fit to content . How is it ?

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="14000px" 
        Width="1312px"></asp:ListBox>

while (dr.Read())
    {

        string poem = dr[0].ToString();
        byte[] newFileData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(poem);

        string fileString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData);
        string[] poem_details = fileString.Split(new string[] { "  ", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach (var line in score_details)
        {

            ListBox1.Items.Add(line);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
Listbox.rows = Listbox.Items.count
```

OR

you can also set size attribute as follows-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#<%=this.ListBox1.ClientID%>').attr('size', $('#<%=this.ListBox1.ClientID%> option').length);
});
```